# How to implement own cast.receiver.media.Player

Tags: android, websocket, google-cast, android-cast-api

**Preface**

I have own player with own native audio engine. Recently I decided to add cast functionality to it. To 'stream' audio to custom cast application I decided to use `WebSocket` and send float32 PCM over it and then play via `WebAudio API`. Because custom audio format, I decided to write my own [cast.receiver.media.Player](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.Player) implementation `sample.MyPlayer`

**Problem**

Once I call `play` or `pause` on `com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer` I got

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current media session

Before call play of course I do `com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer.load` and here interesting moment. And for some reason `sample.MyPlayer` didn't receive `mediaSessionId` looks like this is related to exception on java side somehow. But my `sample.MyPlayer.load` on js side called.

Fragment of log form my application

> cast_receiver.js:61  [ 21.034s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load message 
>   received:{"requestId":2,"media":{ ... },"autoplay":false,"currentTime":0}

Fragment of log from [default receiver sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer)

> cast_receiver.js:61  [ 30.243s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load message received:{"type":"LOAD","requestId":2,"mediaSessionId":0,"customData":null,"media":{ ... },"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0}

As you can see payload in my custom receiver have missing `mediaSessionId`, `type`, `customData` keys

This all I found about a problem.

My `player.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cast Reference Receiver</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
    <div id="player" class="player">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="spinner"></div>
        <div class="watermark"></div>
        <div class="gradient"></div>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="media-info">
                <div class="media-artwork"></div>
                <div class="media-text">
                    <div class="media-title"></div>
                    <div class="media-subtitle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="preview-mode-info">
                <div class="preview-mode-artwork"></div>
                <div class="preview-mode-text">
                    <div class="preview-mode-timer">
                        <div class="preview-mode-timer-starts">Up next in&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="preview-mode-timer-countdown"></div>
                        <div class="preview-mode-timer-sec">&nbsp;secs...</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview-mode-title"></div>
                    <div class="preview-mode-subtitle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <span class="controls-play-pause"></span>
                <span class="controls-cur-time"></span>
                <span class="controls-total-time"></span>
                <div class="controls-progress">
                    <div class="controls-progress-inner progressBar"></div>
                    <div class="controls-progress-thumb"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var mediaManager_ = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(new sample.MyPlayer(), [
            cast.receiver.media.Command.LOAD, 
            cast.receiver.media.Command.PLAY, 
            cast.receiver.media.Command.STOP, 
            cast.receiver.media.Command.GET_STATUS,
            cast.receiver.media.Command.PAUSE, 
            cast.receiver.media.Command.STREAM_VOLUME,
            cast.receiver.media.Command.QUEUE_NEXT,
            cast.receiver.media.Command.QUEUE_PREV
        ]);
      var receiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
      receiverManager.start();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Questions**

1. Is my approach generally right?
2. Where can I found any reference implementation of [cast.receiver.media.Player](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.Player) ? or any recommendations how to implement it properly?
3. What is the problem `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current media session` ?

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. Does your receiver get the correct load payload if you use the default MediaManager?

Comment: @LeonNicholls About wrong payload this is just assumption, because it missing `mediaSessionId`. In my example I always use default `cast.receiver.MediaManager`. Do you mean default `cast.player.api.Player`?